# Javascript SdK facebook Oauth 2.0

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I got auth token for facebook account of a user I stored it in database but when i used it after few days it throws an error exception. *How to get long lived access token*?

Error is the following:

```
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException:
Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1333612800.
```

How to get a token that doesn't expire?

Comment: indeed i do need coz m working on a web app which is autorized by facebook users to get their events.

Comment: @zerkm, he might be trying to get the user data with a cron job or something similar, that is with out user interaction. Jabir, is that the case?

Comment: You must use an access token, maybe an app token will suffice, though I'm not aware of that, are you sure about what you said? Do you have any reference?

Comment: yeah absolutely zerkam i dont need any user interaction once he has authorized my app.Now using access token i want to fetch and publish events.I used facebook javscript SDk to get authorization and token.Just want a long lived access token.

Comment: I never said that it's needed to persist the access token, but it does not change the fact that you need one in order to make api requests. Now, if you're saying that once the user grant the app a specific permission then the app can make the api request with the app token, then ok, I'll need to check up on that, but if you're saying that you don't need a token at all then you are simply wrong. (except for some public information like pages and such).

Comment: I think you're wrong. I used the graph explorer with an app of mine, generated (user) token with "user_events" and checked that I get my events (USER_ID/events), all went well. I then got an app token using curl for the same app, and replaced the user token i had in the graph explorer with this app token, and clicked "submit", instead of getting my events I got an empty array back as the result.

Comment: Yes,I did. Using the [graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), I selected my app on the top right select box, then clicked the "Get Access Token" button and checked the "user events", authorized it with the pop up, the access token was changed to a new one (it's a user token) and indeed "USER_ID/events" worked well, but when i replaced the user token with the app token (a valid one), I got an empty array back. From the [Event doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) I think that only events that were created by the app are accessible using app token

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer: hm, perhaps I was wrong... Hmhmhmh, sorry for being a jerk. Don't even know when I thought it should work :-S

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer: so, I deleted all my comments since I was very wrong in all of them. Also made experiments with local application and I admit you right. Thanks for opening my eyes :-)

Comment: @zerkms: now it seems like I'm replying to an imaginary friend...

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer: sorry for that, but they were 100% irrelevant and incorrect, so no reason to left them

Comment: i am also getting events with the token i got but the problem is that it expires and i am saving token to database and want to use that token to fetch user events.just want to extend token life is there any way to do this???????

Answer (score 0):

You cant have a token that doesnt expire anymore, you can only generate codes that last max 60 days.

Comment: @jonathanromer how do i get that code which lasts for 60 days using javascript SDK.

Comment: Try :  The  'Enhanced Auth Dialog' setting in addition to the 'deprecate offline_access' setting is required to get long lived tokens. You can find it at https://developers.facebook.com/apps